# How do I unit test passport.deserialize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, jestjs, koa

I have a file with my passport.deserializeUser set up like so:

```
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => users.findUser(user.email)
    .then((user) => done(null, user))
    .catch((err) => done(err,null)))
```

But I was wondering how to unit test this? I can test serializeUser by doing a post to register or get signin like so:

```
describe('POST /auth/register', () => {
    test('register new user', async(done) => {
        expect.assertions(2)
        const response = await request(server).post('/auth/register')
            .send(testUser)
        await user.deleteUser(testUser.email)
        expect(response.status).toBe(302)
        expect(response.headers.location).toBe('/auth/status')
        done()
    })
})
```

But to test deserialize I would need to mock a session and then sign out? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: FWIW what you have there is an integration test, and it's testing your API endpoint - it's not unit testing `serializeUser`. These functions are passport related, and nothing more than workflow hooks. I think there would be more value unit testing `users.findUser` given that's where the important code really is.

Comment: This might be of some help: https://mherman.org/blog/stubbing-node-authentication-middleware-with-sinon/